# AngularJS directive/filter for displaying fractions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I am attempting to create a directive and filter to take a number input from a input type number and on blur display it as a fraction (if applicable) and then on focus display it as a decimal.  The model will need to be stored as a decimal.

My current code works if the field is a text field as the model is a fraction, however if I change it to a number field it will not allow for a model update as the string is not a number.  I do not have the on blur/on focus worked out yet but that should be less of an issue than this step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code so far is as follows:

```
.directive('fractionView', ['$filter', function($filter) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
                    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                        var transformedInput = $filter('fraction')(inputValue);

                        if (transformedInput != inputValue && transformedInput) {
                            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                            modelCtrl.$render();
                        }

                        return transformedInput;
                    });
                }
            };
        }])
    .filter('fraction', function() {
        return function(input) {
            function HCF(u, v) {
                var U = u, V = v;
                while (true) {
                    if (!(U %= V))
                        return V;
                    if (!(V %= U))
                        return U;
                }
            }
            return fraction(input);
            //convert a decimal into a fraction
            function fraction(decimal) {

                if (!decimal) {
                    decimal = this;
                }
                whole = String(decimal).split('.')[0];
                decimal = parseFloat("." + String(decimal).split('.')[1]);
                num = "1";
                for (z = 0; z < String(decimal).length - 2; z++) {
                    num += "0";
                }
                decimal = decimal * num;
                num = parseInt(num);
                for (z = 2; z < decimal + 1; z++) {
                    if (decimal % z == 0 && num % z == 0) {
                        decimal = decimal / z;
                        num = num / z;
                        z = 2;
                    }
                }
                //if format of fraction is xx/xxx
                if (decimal.toString().length == 2 &&
                        num.toString().length == 3) {
                    //reduce by removing trailing 0's
                    decimal = Math.round(Math.round(decimal) / 10);
                    num = Math.round(Math.round(num) / 10);
                }
                //if format of fraction is xx/xx
                else if (decimal.toString().length == 2 &&
                        num.toString().length == 2) {
                    decimal = Math.round(decimal / 10);
                    num = Math.round(num / 10);
                }
                //get highest common factor to simplify
                var t = HCF(decimal, num);

                //return the fraction after simplifying it
                if (isNaN((decimal / t)) || isNaN(t)) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    return ((whole == 0) ? "" : whole + " ") + decimal / t + "/" + num / t;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is easier to conceptualize if we look at the the desired functionality on focus and on blur:

- Focus: Display the decimal value.
- Blur: Save the decimal value then compute and display the fractional representation.

Although it may be possible to do this using a single `ngModel` and `$parsers` by converting from decimal to a fraction and vice versa, I think it's simpler to solve if there is a separation between the exposed `ngModel` (the decimal value) and the displayed ngModel (the display/fractional value).

I took a shot at it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/B6vfJxrV65Wj9fjaKXLp?p=preview).

Comment: That looks almost exactly what I was hoping for, the only thing I am having trouble changing is that I want to use the directive as an attribute, binding the focus and blur events on the element within the directive, and swapping the view/model value from there.  Here's my forked plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/s1bBKmCrCKRnY0yDuxm7?p=preview